# Apache OpenJPA - ManyToMany mapping with 3 tables

Tags: java, jpa-2.0

Hello stackoverflow community.

I want to know, if there is a way with (Open)JPA 2.0 to have a mapping with 3 Tables manyToMany?

I Have 3 clases: A, B, C.
The JoinTable would look like: JoinTable={a.id, b.id, c.id}
I found a lot of examples for 2 Entities with manyToMany relation but nothing with 3 Entities.

Can someone tell me the best way to do this? Maybe an example?

EDIT:
I try to show it in db model:

```
A{a.id, a.attribute,...} pk=a.id
B{b.id, b.attribute,...} pk=b.id
C{c.id, c.attribute,...} pk=c.id

Join={a.id,b.id,c.id} pk=(a.id,b.id,c.id)
```

So each Entity has a n to m relation to the other Entities.
I need to get a Collection of B and C for Entity A, Collection of C and A for B etc...

Best Regards
Veote

Comment: It's not quite clear what you mean. Do you have entity `A` which has a relation to both `B` and `C` that you want collected in a single list?